# DevExpress RepositoryItemCheckEdit does not change state when clicking on non-focused node

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using `RepositoryitemCheckEdit` as editor of one of columns in `TreeList`. To change its' state it is necessary that the cell containing checkbox is focused. When I click checkbox of non-focused cell, it gets focused, but checkbox state does not change. Generally I need two clicks to change state of checkbox of non-focused cell, which is not very friendly and I do not see the reason, why it works like this.

Is there any way to make it work on first click(so it is not necessary to have cell focused before you change state of `RepositoryitemCheckEdit`)? I have tried to find some event or property, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the [TreeList.OptionsBehavior.ImmediateEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeListOptionsBehavior_ImmediateEditortopic) is set to `true`:

```
this.treeList1.OptionsBehavior.ImmediateEditor = true;
```